# Dynamic Date Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Is there a way to cycle through consecutive data values for a variable in my code?

My date variable updates every Saturday, so whenever I update my table I have to manually backdate the code by changing the data variable every execution. This is a very lengthy process as I am backdating 30+ dates with a code that takes 1-2 minutes to run.

For example, if I loaded a secondary table with the date of every Saturday in 2020-2021 (for now), could I cycle the variable through the values?

```
Declare @Saturday Date
Set @Saturday = '2021-04-24'

Declare @Friday Date
Set @Friday = '2021-04-30'
;
```

Comment: You could just join your calendar table. If you give your full code we could see what we can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar thing where I had to recalculate values per day and if some configuration changed we had to backdate those changes per day for x number of days

I used something like this to achieve the result, essentially starting at the furtherst point back and moving forwards but you can run it the other way if that is preferable. On the other hand the code I was running would take a few seconds per execution rather than 1-2 minutes.

```
Declare @Saturday Date
Set @Saturday = '2020-01-04';

while @Saturday < GETDATE()

begin
print @saturday; /*do something*/
set @Saturday = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Saturday);
end
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the way forward. It works for the first run, but all subsequent runs pull no rows through. May be due to having both a "@Saturday" and "@Friday" variable in my code. My "@Friday" variable was set as "dateadd(day,6,@Saturday)". Can I apply both variables in the way you have shown?

Comment: Update: it does work by adding the @Friday variable in exactly the same way you have done. Thanks so much - this has saved me A LOT of time!